# Is it possible to use FTP without filesystem in client?

Tags: filesystems, ip, ftp, tcpip

Is it possible to use FTP protocol (not TFTP) to get file from ftp server to ftp client without using filesystem in client ?

**EDIT**:

The motives behind the question: I know that tftp can do it, but not ftp. Yet, someone told me that he use some ipstack (NicheStack) with wftpd server in PC, and without any filesystem in the target (client).

Yet, I am still not sure about it. Does anyone knows if it is possible ?

Comment: did you have anything in mind for what you wanted to use if not the file system? I guess in theory some software could put it in RAM without committing it to disk.

Comment: **Yes it is possible** --- If you want a more specific answer you will have to tell us more about what you want to do.

Comment: The motives behind the question: I know that tftp can do it, but not ftp. yet, someone told me that he use some ipstack (NicheStack) with wftpd server in PC, and without any filesystem in the target (client).

Comment: @MartinPrikryl Technically if you wrote an answer to the question then it'd answer the question, (when he hadn't added specifics). Now he has added specifics it's debatable whether you trying to answer it would apply.  So it's possible that you've made a potential answer you could've given irrelevant.

Comment: @ransh what do you mean by client no file system, like do you mean they store it in RAM only?

Comment: Your edit does not change anything about question. -- Again ***Yes it is possible***, no matter what someone told you. See also the answer by @Steffen.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

FTP is a protocol to transfer data where the data are associated with some identifier (i.e. a name). While these properties are commonly met by files on a file system this can also be a database or some in-memory key-value store or any other kind of data which are associated with an identifier.

Of course - this is FTP as a protocol, not as a specific implementation as server or client. But common toolkits like ftplib in Python actually support transfer of data which are only in-memory and not on a file system.